# Sails.js best practice in using transactions with promises (Postgres)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails 0.9.16 with Postgres and my question is: what is the best way to execute transaction using current API with promises? May be there is something better than:

```
    Model.query('BEGIN TRANSACTION', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        Model
          .create(...)
          .(function (value) {
            return [value, RelatedModel.create(...).then(...)];
          })
          .fail(function (err) {
            Model.query('ROLLBACK');
            next(err);
          })
          .spread(function (...) {
            Model.query('COMMIT')
            next(...);
          })
      }
    })
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hey how did you solve the problem or which was the best way for doing it for you?

Comment: Since Sails postgres adapter pulls/creates new connection for every single query I've end up with adapter modification: https://gist.github.com/zuker/62cd680d58a8f218e87d

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm currently using this exact workflow. For executing one query with promises do this:

```
Model
 .query(params)
 .then(function(result){
 //act on result
 })
 .catch(function(error){
 //handle error
 })
 .done(function(){
 //clean up
 });
```

To execute multiple queries in parallel, do this:

```
var Promise = require('q');

Promise.all([

    User.findOne(),
    AnotherModel.findOne(),
    AnotherModel2.find()

])
.spread(function(user,anotherModel,anotherModel2){
    //use the results
})
.catch(function(){
    //handle errors
})
.done(function(){
    //clean up
});
```

If you're trying to avoid nesting in your code:

```
Model
.query(params)
.then(function(result){//after query #1
    //since you're returning a promise here, you can use .then after this
    return Model.query();
})
.then(function(results){//after query#2
    if(!results){
        throw new Error("No results found in query #2");
    }else{
        return Model.differentQuery(results);
    }

})
.then(function(results){
//do something with the results
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
})
.done(function(){
    //cleanup
});
```

**Note:** currently, waterline uses Q for promises. There is a pull request to switch waterline from Q to bluebird here: [waterline/bluebird](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/487)

When I answered this question, I'd yet to take the database class in college, so I didn't know what a transaction was. I did some digging, and bluebird allows you to do transactions with promises. The only problem is, this isn't exactly built into sails since it's some what of a special use case. Here's the code bluebird provides for this situation.

```
var pg = require('pg');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(pg);

function getTransaction(connectionString) {
    var close;
    return pg.connectAsync(connectionString).spread(function(client, done) {
        close = done;
        return client.queryAsync('BEGIN').then(function () {
            return client;
        });
    }).disposer(function(client, promise) {
        if (promise.isFulfilled()) {
            return client.queryAsync('COMMIT').then(closeClient);
        } else {
            return client.queryAsync('ROLLBACK').then(closeClient);
        }
        function closeClient() {
            if (close) close(client);
        }
    });
}

exports.getTransaction = getTransaction;
```

Comment: can you give bluebird equivalent, since waterline has shifted to bluebird

Comment: @lujaw the code for the bluebird equivalent should be exactly the same as they both adhere to the A+ promise spec.

Comment: @aclave1 In the third example how can I return two objects or variables in the second `then` to the third `then`. I mean the result from the firs query and another resulto made on the second query and receive those in the third `then`? I hope to explain a little bit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Lexynux You'll want to look at Bluebird's 
Promise.Join(result1,result2).spread(function(result1,result2){

})

or at Promise.bind() depending on your use case

Comment: Do you have any example? My code looks like this and it doesn't work!

Comment: Can you please post a question and post a link in the comments for me?

Comment: @aclave1 Here it is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641985/how-to-return-two-objects-in-a-promise-using-sails

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with transactions is when they are wrapped properly by a promise library, because transaction logic maps perfectly into the promise event chain, one doesn't have to worry about when to do `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, as it happens automatically.

Here's a complete example of how it works with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library:

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);

var cn = "postgres://username:password@host:port/database";
var db = pgp(cn); // database instance;

db.tx(t => {
    // BEGIN has been executed
    return t.batch([
        t.one("insert into users(name) values($1) returning id", 'John'),
        t.one("insert into users(name) values($1) returning id", 'Mike')
    ]);
})
    .then(data => {
        // COMMIT has been executed
        console.log(data[0].id); // print id assigned to John;
        console.log(data[1].id); // print id assigned to Mike;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ROLLBACK has been executed
        console.log(error); // print why failed;
    });
```

Comment: This looks like awesome logic to work with in SailsJS but how do I know when to use promises and when use simple code?

Comment: By simple code - do you mean callbacks? The asynchronous nature of your code and libraries dictates what should be used.

Comment: But I have read that promises are used most we you need to have to many nested callbacks in order to have clean code. Is it true?

Comment: @AlexVentura no, promises is the new standard for asynchronous programming in Node.js. And new things like ES6 generators and ES7 async/await automatically work with the promise standard. See [examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/examples/select-insert.md).

Comment: Alright, so it better to use than callbacks in any case?

Comment: @AlexVentura that's right. And when you start chaning results from many methods you will see the benefit, as with callbacks it can quickly turn into an unreadable nested nightmare.